# Basic javascript while loop syntax

Tags: javascript, syntax, while-loop

I'm coding a function in javascript using a while loop, fairly similar to what's listed below.

```
{
    var x="",i=0;
    while (i<5)
    {
        x=x + "The number is " + i + "<br>";
        i++;
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
}
```

Now in this code, the document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x; code is executed despite being outside the while loop brackets, and code outside next set of brackets generates syntax errors, as it belongs to no function.

How would I execute a single command after the while loop in the function?

Comment: The line `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;` is executed **once**. It shows all the iterations since you add all of them to `x`. What is the problem?

Comment: Code outside the brackets doesn't generate syntax errors. Javascript code doesn't have to be in a function. Your code works as written.

Comment: I see. Basically, my problem is I didn't understand what I was printing, not the syntax of the loop.  Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: Proper code indentation (which I corrected in your posted example) makes the code a lot easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

The line
`document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;` is executed one time. It correctly shows all the iterations since you add all of them to `x` each loop.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Kindly format code with breves (`). Thanks for your answer!